# How to add onPress events on Cards (on native base)?

Tags: react-native, native-base

I'm trying to make those cards clickable to redirect to another screen, but I cant figure it out

```
 let cards = this.state.items.map(item => (
            <Card key={item.id} onPress={() => Actions.dogScreen()}> 
                <CardItem bordered>
                    <Left>
                        <Thumbnail square source={item.image ? { uri: "data:image/jpeg;base64," + item.image } : logo} />
                        <Body>
                            <Text>Name: {item.name}, Age: {item.age}</Text>
                            <Text note>Gender: {item.gender.name} Race: {item.race.name}</Text>
                        </Body>
                    </Left>
                </CardItem>
            </Card>))
```

Comment: From which library are you importing `Card` ?

Comment: from 'native-base'

Comment: I will answer @Guilherme

Answer (score 14):

You can make `<Card />` clickable by wrapping the whole card by `TouchableOpacity`. Also don't forget to add `pointerEvents="none"` for each card.

```
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

let cards = this.state.items.map(item => (
     <TouchableOpacity key={item.id} onPress={() => Actions.dogScreen()}>         

          <Card pointerEvents="none"> 
                <CardItem bordered>
                    <Left>
                        <Thumbnail square source={item.image ? { uri: "data:image/jpeg;base64," + item.image } : logo} />
                        <Body>
                            <Text>Name: {item.name}, Age: {item.age}</Text>
                            <Text note>Gender: {item.gender.name} Race: {item.race.name}</Text>
                        </Body>
                    </Left>
                </CardItem>
            </Card>

       </TouchableOpacity>
))
```

Comment: CardItem is already having onPress. Is it not possible to use instead of wrapping it in "TouchableOpacity"?